# 2D Hookes Law derivation

Tags: classical-mechanics, solid-state-physics

I am currently deriving the matrix form for 2D Hookes Law equation with poissons ratio, where $y$ is longitudinal and $x$ is lateral

$$v = -\frac{\epsilon_x}{\epsilon_y}$$

[image]

We can derive the total elongation from the forces in the x direction as so where L is the width or length of the shape
$$d_x = (\epsilon_{x1} + \epsilon_{x2}) L_x$$

Since we know that poissons ratio, we know $\epsilon_{x2} = v \cdot \epsilon_y$
$$ d_x = (\frac{\sigma_x}{E} - v \frac{\sigma_y}{E})L_x $$

And using that logic we derive the total displacement in the y direction

$$d_y = (\epsilon_{y1} + \epsilon_{y2}) L_x$$

Since we know that poissons ratio, we know $\epsilon_{y2} = \frac{\epsilon_x}{v}$
$$ d_y = (\frac{\sigma_y}{E} - \frac{\sigma_x}{v \cdot E})L_y $$

However, its not! I don't understand where I'm going wrong, instead it's supposed to be
$$ d_y = (\frac{\sigma_y}{E} - v \frac{\sigma_x}{E})L_y $$

Can someone kindly point out my logical flaw?
Cheers

Comment: you image cut off a lot of information I think,  hard to check check your equations.

Comment: No worries, I have added the whole slide now :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no flaw here. Your equations are exactly what you see in matrix form

$$ \pmatrix{ \frac{d_x}{L_x} \\ \frac{d_y}{L_y} } = \pmatrix{ \epsilon_x \\ \epsilon_y} = \frac{1}{E} \begin{bmatrix}
1 & -\nu \\ -\nu & 1
 \end{bmatrix} \pmatrix{\sigma_x \\ \sigma_y } $$

What exactly are you asking then?